# Why is my python output repeating itself and not searching through the whole file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no idea why this is happening I am very new to python lol I was wondering if any of you know.
My goal is to print the number of occurrences for a certain row then display the total next to it.
I have another test csv file that is much smaller and seems to work better. The csv I need to run it on had hundreds of thousands of entries so I dont know if thats the problem or not.

I also get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\riley\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\no library.py", line 9, in 
for row in csv_data:
File "C:\Users\riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 357: character maps to .
anything helps, thanks.

```
count = collections.Counter()

for row in csv_data:
    username = row[0]
    department = row[1]
    password = row[2]
    count[password] += 1

    total_duplications = 0

    for password, occurance in count.items():
        if occurance > 1:
            total_duplications += occurance
            print(password, occurance)
        else:
            total_duplications += 0
```

Comment: Not the cause of the exception, but should you deindent the second loop outside of the first one? This would avoid having your program "*repeat itself*"

Comment: Can you specify the encoding you're using?

Comment: The message says your file contains the byte value `0x8f` which is one of the very few byte values not defined in the Windows character set. I would guess your file is in UTF-8, but with no more to go on than you provide, guessing is all it is. Open your file in a decent text editor like Notepad++ (free) and it will provide a well-founded estimate of the encoding. Then open the file specifying that encoding using `encoding=`. On Windows the default is Windows-1252 which is clearly wrong in this case.

Comment: Im using UTF-8 encoding I believe. Also when I unindent my second loop nothing works...